# str_replace on whole words

Tags: php, str-replace

- I have many `arrays` contain many words.
- I want to apply a `CSS` style to these words appear in a text
- One array correspond to one color
- I want whole word only

I have an exemple with `str_replace`, it works but not considere whole words.
`$result['avisits']`, `$result['avisPronoums']` and `$result['avisWordsUser']` are string contain word with `"\n"` separate on database.
`$result['avis']` is a string contain text where i want to replace words

```
$arr1 = explode("\n", $result['avisits']);
$arr2 = $arr1;
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr1); ++$i) {
    $arr1[$i] = "<font color='red'><u>".$arr1[$i]."</u></font>";
}

$avis = str_replace($arr2, $arr1, $result['avis']);

$arr3 = explode("\n", $result['avisPronoums']);
$arr4 = $arr3;
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr3); ++$i) {
    $arr3[$i] = "<span style='background:Yellow'>".$arr3[$i]."</span>";
}
$avis2 = str_replace($arr4, $arr3, $avis);

$arr5 = explode("\n", $result['avisWordsUser']);
$arr6 = $arr5;
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr5); ++$i) {
    $arr5[$i] = "<span style='background:GreenYellow'>".$arr5[$i]."</span>";
}

$avis3 = str_replace($arr6, $arr5, $avis2);
```

Comment: Please explain more about `$result['avisits']` , `$result['avis']` , `$avis` default values.

Comment: why do you have to replace at all just do recursive loops and replace words before you generate the output or give a better example whats the input and what you expect to replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly `$result['avis']` is the string you want to format word by word?
You could try to explode your text with `' '`, which will separate it in words and then do direct comparisons word by word and then implode it back.

```
$avis = explode(' ', $result['avis']);
$cnt = count($avis); // Don't use count() in your for loops it is a huge perfomance hit
for($i=0; $i < $cnt; $i++){
    if(in_array($avis[$i], $arr1)){
         $avis[$i] = "<font color='red'><u>".$avis[$i]."</u></font>";
    }
    elseif(in_array($avis[$i], $arr3))...
    // Do the other replacements here
}
$avis = implode(' ', $avis);
```

Answer (score 1):

`str_replace()` isn't smart enough to determine what is or is not a "whole word"; you'll need to use [`preg_replace()`](https://secure.php.net/preg_replace):

```
$avis = preg_replace(sprintf('/\b%s\b/', preg_quote($arr2)), $arr1, $result['avis']);
// ...
$avis2 = preg_replace(sprintf('/\b%s\b/', preg_quote($arr4)), $arr3, $avis);
// ...
$avis3 = preg_replace(sprintf('/\b%s\b/', preg_quote($arr6)), $arr5, $avis2);
```

Comment: $chaine = "cinglê à connacinglédo cingle cinglétecinglê cinglê tecinglé";
$arr9 = ['foo', 'cinglê', 'boo'];
$arr10 = $arr9;
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr9); ++$i) {
  $arr9[$i] = "<span style='background:GreenYellow'>".$arr9[$i]."</span>";
}
$avis = preg_replace(sprintf('/\b%s\b/', preg_quote($arr10)), $arr9, $chaine);
echo $avis . '<br/>';